# HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type error when passing data from ajax to restfull server as json

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to send data with ajax as json to restful service. But something is not done right. I get this error

[image]

I read that that's maybe because I didn't add some jar files, so this are the files that I have:
[image]

My ajax function looks like this:

```
var url1 = "../web.projekat/rest/korisnici/registracija";

    $('#btnReg').click(function(){

            var memail = document.getElementById('email').value;
            var mkorIme = document.getElementById('korIme').value;
            var mpass = document.getElementById('pass1').value;


            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : url1,
                contentType : 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                dataType : "text",
                data : formToJSON(mkorIme, mpass, "ds", "dsdsd", "Menadzer",  "06315487", memail, "dsds"), 
                success : function(){
                    alert("Success");
                },

                error : function(){
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
    });
});


function formToJSON(korIme, lozinka, ime, prezime, uloga, telefon, email, slika) {
    return JSON.stringify({
        "korIme" : korIme,
        "lozinka": lozinka,
        "ime": ime,
        "prezime": prezime,
        "uloga": uloga,
        "telefon": telefon,
        "email" : email,
        "slika": slika,
    });
}
```

My html file with the form looks like this:

```
<form action="../web.projekat/rest/korisnici/registracija" id="regForm" method="post">
        <div class="form_container">

            <div id="email_div">
                <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email adresa">
                <span class="error">Unesite validnu email adresu.</span>
            </div>

            <div id="korIme_div">
                <input id="korIme" type="text" placeholder="Korisnicko ime"> 
                <span class="error">Unesite korisnicko ime.</span>
            </div>

            <div id="pass1_div">
                <input id="pass1" type="password" placeholder="Lozinka">
                <span class="error">Unesite lozinku.</span>
            </div>

            <div id="pass2_div">
                <input id="pass2" type="password" placeholder="Ponovite lozinku">
                <span class="error">Unesite lozinku ponovo.</span>
            </div>

            <input id="btnReg" type="submit" value="Registruj se">

            <p>Vec ste registrovani? <a href="prijava">Prijavite se.</a></p>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And my web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>web.projekat</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>html/registration_form.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>controller</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And finally my rest service class looks like this:

```
@Path("/korisnici")
public class KorisnikServis {

    @Context
    HttpServletRequest request;
    @Context
    ServletContext ctx;

    @POST
    @Path("/registracija")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String registracija(Korisnik data) {
        return "sdasd";
    }
}
```

Nothing is returned while the argument is *Korisnik data*, when I change it to *String data* it returning the data.

My *Korisnik* class has all the parameters and condtructors and getters and setters.

So why can't my application recognize the data that's sent ass json? It is returning the ***HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type*** error.
Thank you for your help.

**UPDATE**

My Korisnik class code

```
public class Korisnik {
    public String kor_ime;
    public String lozinka;
    public String ime;
    public String prezime;
    public String uloga;
    public String telefon;
    public String email;
    public String slika;

    public Korisnik(){}

    public Korisnik(String kor_ime, String lozinka, String ime, String prezime, String uloga, String telefon, String email,
            String slika) {
        super();
        this.kor_ime = kor_ime;
        this.lozinka = lozinka;
        this.ime = ime;
        this.prezime = prezime;
        this.uloga = uloga;
        this.telefon = telefon;
        this.email = email;
        this.slika = slika;
    }

    public String getKor_ime() {
        return kor_ime;
    }

    public void setKor_ime(String kor_ime) {
        this.kor_ime = kor_ime;
    }

    public String getLozinka() {
        return lozinka;
    }

    public void setLozinka(String lozinka) {
        this.lozinka = lozinka;
    }

    public String getIme() {
        return ime;
    }

    public void setIme(String ime) {
        this.ime = ime;
    }

    public String getPrezime() {
        return prezime;
    }

    public void setPrezime(String prezime) {
        this.prezime = prezime;
    }

    public String getUloga() {
        return uloga;
    }

    public void setUloga(String uloga) {
        this.uloga = uloga;
    }

    public String getTelefon() {
        return telefon;
    }

    public void setTelefon(String telefon) {
        this.telefon = telefon;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getSlika() {
        return slika;
    }

    public void setSlika(String slika) {
        this.slika = slika;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Korisnik [kor_ime=" + kor_ime + ", ime=" + ime + ", prezime=" + prezime + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your `Korisnik` model code? Also are you sending your request with the `content-type: application/json` header?

Comment: What do you mean by "sending your request with the content-type: application/json header:? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Nevermind I see you are in your AJAX method.

Answer (score 1):

In your AJAX request, you are specifying your `dataType` as text, which is why your web service is only accepting a String. Change your `dataType` to `application/json`.

EDIT:

This actually is wrong, you would probably be seeing a different error. You should try setting your contentType in your AJAX request to be just `application/json` (remove `;charset=utf-8`).

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, I tried what you said and still the same error comes out.